# Out of a java program

Tags: java

Java newbie here, I am trying to find the output of the following chunk of code: I know i am missing some fundamentals of java but if someone can guide me i would appreciate it.

```
public class Test4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C(1, 2); // creates an obj c with arguments
        D d = (D) c; // creates class obj 'D' and casts 'c' to D?
        System.out.println(d.getP());
        System.out.println(d.getProd());
    }
}

public class C {
    protected int m;
    protected int n;
    protected static int kappa = 0;

    public C(int m1) {
        this.m = m1;
        this.n = m1;
        kappa = kappa + 2;
    }

    public C(int m1, int n1) {
        this.m = m1;
        this.n = n1;
        kappa = kappa + 2;
    }

    public int getSum() {
        return m + n;
    }

    public int getProd() {
        return m * n;
    }

    public static int getKappa() {
        return kappa;
    }
}

public class D extends C {
    private int p;

    public D(int p1) {
        super(p1);
        this.p = p1;
    }

    public D(int k1, int n1, int p1) {
        super(k1, n1);
        p = p1;
    }

    public int getP() {
        return p;
    }

    public int getSum() {
        return m + n + p;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can find the output by compiling and running it.

Comment: Why don't you just run the file?

Comment: i am an ultra noob, i am having issues running this using netbeans. do i just create 2 different classes (D and C) with the main class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your D class extends C so you can use D as type of C (`C c = new D();`) but not C as type of D (this is wrong `D d = new C();`.

So in your code

```
C c = new C(1, 2); // creates an obj c with arguments
D d = (D) c; // <--this will generate ClassCastException
```

Comment: i dont think there are any errors with the code above... shouldnt generate an exception... as I have the correct answers too for the output. its 6 and 4.

Comment: so if i did, D d= new D (1,2,3) and next line C c1 = d. would this give an error?

Comment: @user1477348 if you do D d= new D (1,2,3) it will work with output 3 and 2

Comment: @user1477348 If you want to receive output 6 and 4 try maybe `D d = new D(2,3,4)`.